# Creating objects inheriting from User with existing User in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have my user models like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AUser(User):
    # some model properties

class BUser(User):
    # some model properties
```

Here `AUser` has different web interface and `BUser` has different web interface. If a user signup in `AUser` interface, I will create a user for him like this.

```
auser = AUser.objects.create(username='abc', first_name='abc', last_name='cdf', email='abc@gmail.com')
auser.set_password('asdf12345')
```

Same thing I will do for creating account in `BUser` interface. As `AUser` and `BUser` inherit `User` model, they have a field `user_ptr` which is actually `User` object.

The problem is If a user has already an account in `AUser` interface, then if he tries to login with same credentials in `BUser` interface, I will automatically create `BUser` object for him but with same credentials. Which means I will not create `User` object but I will attach a `BUser` object with existing `User` object. But I cannot find a way to create object like this. I tried to do it like this

```
user = User.objects.get(id=123)
buser = BUser.objects.create(user_ptr=user)
```

But it try to create new `User` object with default values. How can I create a new `BUser` object with existing `User` object in this case?

PS: Though it is not good idea to inherit `User` model but it is a running project. So I cannot change my structure.

Comment: show the user_ptr field in BUser model

Comment: Typically in object-oriented programming, you can not "change" the type of an object (not even subclassing it),  Based on what you post here, it looks like you do not want to subclass, but attach a "role" to it, and thus *remove* the old role, and add a new one.

Comment: @Exprator: I think he means the "implicit" reference when you subclass a model.

Comment: @Exprator `user_ptr` is not in `BUser` model. In fact it is created when we inherit `User` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this using raw sql queries because I did not find a way using Django ORM for doing this. I did it like this.

```
def insert_with_raw_query(table, data):
    values_keys = ','.join(data.keys())
    data_values = ''
    for v in data.values():
        if v == 'TRUE' or v == 'FALSE':
            data_values += ('%s,' % v)
        else:
            if isinstance(v, str):
                data_values += ("'%s'," % v)
            else:
                data_values += ('%s,' % str(v))

    insert_query = 'INSERT INTO "app_{table}"({values_keys}) VALUES ({data});'.format(
        table=table.lower(),
        values_keys=values_keys,
        data=data_values[:-1])

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(insert_query)

    return True
```